# Fail to link after compile: disk quota exceeded

Tags: c++, c, makefile, linker, fortran

I'm compiling code that's predominantly in C, with parts in C++/Fortran. When I perform the final link after compilation,

```
mpicc -std=c11 -g -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -funroll-loops OBJECT FILES
-L/LIBRARIES -o /scratch/my_scratch_dir/my_executable
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/ld: final link failed: Disk quota exceeded
make: *** [Makefile:2256: /scratch/my_scratch_dir/my_executable] Error 1
```

I have cleaned up a significant fraction of data in `/scratch/my_scratch_dir`, as I thought that there was no space for `my_executable`. However, this has not made any difference.

With a bit of Googling I found that during the final link, files may be stored `/tmp`, which may therefore also be over-filled. However, when I check the disk usage via `df -h`, the maximum to which any `/tmp` directory is filled is 10%.

The other "clue" I tried to follow was the reference to `/bin/ld`, but I'm on a public computer and don't have read/write access to `/bin`, so I would assume that any disk quota problems affecting `/bin` would affect all users of the computer, which is not the case.

I'm therefore wondering which directory I need to clean up, in order to get my final link to work?

Comment: Run `quota` to see which filesystem you are hitting limits on.

Comment: Hmm, I get no return if I run `quota` from any of the directories mentioned in the question...

Comment: Is there some static-storage object in your program that (perhaps accidentally) takes a huge amount of space? Does free disk space decrease a lot during the link?

Comment: Reduce it to a [mre].

Comment: Also `df -h` may help